# separable space and open covers

Tags: general-topology

If a topological space $X$ is separable, then every open cover of $X$ must be countable? 
since $X$ is separable , then there exists a countable dense subset $S$. This implies, in every open cover any set must intersect with $S$.

Comment: Did you also see this?:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241530/if-x-is-a-topological-separable-space-then-every-open-set-is-a-union-of-a-coun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, definitely not. The [Mrówka space $\Psi$](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/mrowka-space/) is a separable space with an irreducible open cover of cardinality $2^\omega=\mathfrak{c}$. (*Irreducible* means that it has no proper subcover.) The [Katětov extension](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/336119/12042) of $\Bbb N$ is a separable space that has an irreducible open cover of cardinality $2^{2^\omega}=2^{\mathfrak{c}}$.

Comment: But each member of the cover must be intersect with dense subset. so, where is my mistake? ı could not see. I mean that which set must be countable?

Comment: @ghb: A countable set has $2^\omega$ different subsets. Moreover, two different open sets can have the same intersection with a dense subset.

Comment: I see now, thanks.

Comment: @ghb: You’re welcome.

Comment: If you don't demand an *irreducible* open cover, even the particular point topology on an infinite set will do the trick.

Comment: @dfeuer: My default assumption is that all spaces are $T_1$. (And here I did better: $\Psi$ is Tikhonov, and $\kappa\Bbb N$ is Hausdorff.)